# Handling missing arguments, handled with missing(), to call a function inside a function

Tags: r

I am using `rpart()` inside a function `myFunction()`.  `rpart()` accepts several parameters which are handled using the `missing()` function:

> `rpart(formula, data, weights, subset, na.action = na.rpart, method, model = FALSE, x = FALSE, y = TRUE, parms, control, cost, ...)`

For example, the parameter `method` can be left unspecified, and is handled inside `rpart()` using the following code:

`if (missing(method)) method <- "whatever default"`

**How can I pass the argument `method` as a parameter for `myFunction()` in the most simple and efficient way so that it handles the default missing argument?**

If I do something like
`myFunction(foo = 0, method){# somecode; rpart(y ~ x, data = data, method = method)}`
then this throws an error,

> argument "method" is missing, with no default

I have also tried with functions like `rlang::missing()` with no success whatsoever.

Of course an option is doing something like passing `myFunction(method = NULL)` and then using if-else statements to either pass or not pass this argument, but then I have to code each possibility (for 4 arguments that would be 16 calls) and is very clumsy.

Note that I would also like to avoid using the ellipsis, as I want to specifically name my arguments.

---

MINIMAL REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE:

```
y <- c(0,0.1,0.1,-0.1, 100, 101, 99)
x <- c(1,2,3,4, 100,101,102)

myFunction <- function(x, y,
                       method,
                       weights,
                       subset,
                       parms){
      rpart(formula = y ~ .,
            data = data.frame(y, x),
            weights = weights,
            subset = subset,
            parms = parms)
}

myFunction(x,y)
```

> Error in eval(extras, data, env) :    argument "weights" is missing,
> with no default

Comment: I tried with this example `f <- function(x){if (missing(x)) x <- "default";x};g <- function(x){f(x = x)}` but I don't have an error.

Comment: @MrFlick I have updated with the error message. I can pass a parameter if I specify one, but I want to be able to left the default (missing) parameter. I.e. not specifying `method` in `myFunction()` should work as not specifying it in `rpart()`

Comment: I think you're describing what `...` is for. `myFunction(foo = 0, ...) {# somecode; rpart(y ~ x, data = data, ...)}`?

Comment: Well the error message here talks about "weights" but that doesn't seem to be used in your example. Missing parameters are normally properly passed, for example `f1 <- function(x) {print(missing(x))}; f2 <- function(x) {f1(x)}; f2()`. There are no errors there. So it's unclear exactly what you are doing that would result in errors. A reproducible example would be something we can copy/paste into R to run and test.

Comment: @MrFlick The weights thing was a typo when pasting it here.

Comment: Are you evaluating/modifying `method` before the call to `rpart`?

Comment: @MrFlick I have added a reproducible example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution using `match.call`. This kind of pattern is seen quite often inside base R functions.

Consider the following function which we might find inside a package, with optional arguments:

```r
package_fun <- function(x, method1, method2, method3)
{
  if(missing(method1)) method1 <- "Unspecified"
  if(missing(method2)) method2 <- "Unspecified"
  if(missing(method3)) method3 <- "Unspecified"
  data.frame(x, method1, method2, method3)
}
```

Inside our own function, we can build a call to `package_fun` that swaps in our own optional parameters, swaps out any we don't want to pass, and adds any additional ones we choose. We are left with a single call to `package_fun`, and don't need to worry about combinatorial explosion:

```
myFunction <- function(foo = 0, method1, method2, method3)
{
  mc <- match.call()
  mc[[1]] <- quote(package_fun)
  mc <- mc[-which(names(mc) == "foo")]
  mc$x <- foo
  eval(mc, env = parent.frame())
}
```

So now we can do:

```
myFunction(foo = 1, method1 = "Specified", method3 = "Specified")
#>   x   method1     method2   method3
#> 1 1 Specified Unspecified Specified
```

From the point of view of your reproducible example, this would look like:

```r
myFunction <- function(x, y,
                       method,
                       weights,
                       subset,
                       parms){
  mc <- match.call()
  mc[[1]] <- quote(rpart)
  mc$formula <- y ~ .
  mc$data <- data.frame(y, x)
  mc$x <- NULL
  mc$y <- NULL
  eval(mc, envir =parent.frame())
}
```

So we would have:

```r
myFunction(x,y)
#> n= 7 
#> 
#> node), split, n, deviance, yval
#>       * denotes terminal node
#> 
#> 1) root 7 17136.31 42.87143 *
```

Comment: I would also add in `myFunction()` statements like `if (!missing(method)) mc$method <- method` (same for the rest of parameters), Right?

Comment: @D1X No, you don't need to. They will already be there in the call. Check my first example. The non-missing `method1` and `method2` get passed without you having to do anything. The very first package function handles the missing arguments - this is like `rpart` handling missing arguments. Your function doesn't need to do that if the missing arguments are handled already by `rpart`

Comment: Amusingly, `rpart` uses this approach (see the first `else` in it) and it causes the issue (because a `weight` is passed to `model.frame` whereas on a top level call to `rpart` this wouldn't happen).

Comment: Yep, I see! Thanks! Could you elaborate on what `envir = parent.frame()` does? I will be using the call `eval(mc, envir = parent.frame())` inside a future_lapply() loop, and it does not find function `rpart()`

Comment: @Roland yes, there are a few functions where the call to `model.frame` is built this way, and it doesn't play nicely with `*apply` type functions.

Comment: @D1X If you are using it inside an `apply` type function, this might be a problem. The `envir = parent.frame()` tells the `eval` function which evaluation frame you wish to use. It might work if you set `envir = environment(myFunction)`

Comment: Okay, it works setting `eval(mc, envir = environment(rpart))`. Also, if `myFunction()` has more arguments (for other computations and not for `rpart()`) they need to be set to `NULL` in `mc`. Thanks for your help. Still, I am amazed by how complex this turned out to be. I usually handle missing args using `NULL` as default value.